# Is there any ecological modifier which can be added to PLA to make it not brittle, and good for some heavier-duty outdoor food-grade use?

Tags: materials, material-science

Is there any modifier which can be added to PLA to make it not brittle, and good for some heavier-duty outdoor food-grade use?

The criteria is that adding the modifier still keeps the material biodegradable.

Comment: I think that still wouldn't make it strong enough.

Comment: It does not need to be 3d printed, could be a variety of other molding techniques.